# Orthonormal eigenspinors of the gauge-covariant dirac operator on $\mathbb{R}^4$, with extra conditions are possible?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, spin-geometry

Let $G$ be a simple Lie group, and $V$ a representation.

Consider $\mathbb{R}^4$ with its flat Euclidean metric. Let $P$ be the trivial $G$-bundle on $\mathbb R^4$ equipped with some (non-trivial) connection $A$, and let $E=V\times \mathbb R^4$ be the associated vector bundle. Finally, let $S$ be the spinor bundle on $\mathbb{R}^4$.

We can then use the connection $A$ to define the gauge-covariant Dirac operator $D_A$ on the space of sections of $S \otimes E$. (I assume that the components of $A$ are smooth and integrable on $\mathbb{R}^4$.)

My questions are as follows:

1. I have found references saying that when the underlying Riemannian manifold is compact, the Dirac operator $D_A$ is essentially self-adjoint and has an orthonormal eigenbasis. What asymptotic conditions at infinity do I have to impose on $A$ to ensure that the same results holds on $\mathbb{R}^4$?
2. I also have found references saying that the Dirac operator is elliptic. Does this imply together with the above setting that we can find some eigenspinors of $D_A$ whose components are smooth and bounded on $\mathbb{R}^4$? If so, how can one prove this?